# How can I dynamically return a Diesel equality expression from a helper method?

Tags: mysql, rust, rust-diesel

I have an enum:

```
enum Role {
    Administrator,
    Sponsor,
    Bot,
}
```

and I have a table in my database called "roles" that looks like this:

```
| user_id | administrator | sponsor | bot   |
|---------|---------------|---------|-------|
| 0       | true          | false   | false |
| 1       | false         | false   | false |
| 2       | false         | true    | true  |
```

How can I perform a match on a `Role` and obtain the corresponding column in my database while using [Diesel](https://diesel.rs/) and not a raw SQL query?

I can return a Diesel expression from a method that matches on a role, but it isn't working with my insert statement:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;

use diesel::{
    mysql::{Mysql, MysqlConnection},
    sql_types::{Bool, Nullable},
    BoxableExpression, Connection, ExpressionMethods, RunQueryDsl,
};
use schema::{roles, users};
use models::{NewUser};

use std::error::Error;

mod schema {
    table! {
        roles (user_id) {
            id -> Unsigned<Bigint>,
            user_id -> Unsigned<Bigint>,
            administrator -> Nullable<Bool>,
            sponsor -> Nullable<Bool>,
            bot -> Nullable<Bool>,
        }
    }

    table! {
        users (id) {
            id -> Unsigned<Bigint>,
            username -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        }
    }

    allow_tables_to_appear_in_same_query!(
        roles,
        users,
    );
}

mod models {
    use super::schema::users;

    #[derive(Insertable, PartialEq, Debug, Default)]
    #[table_name = "users"]
    pub struct NewUser<'a> {
        username: &'a str,
    }

    impl<'a> NewUser<'a> {
        pub fn new(username: &'a str) -> Self {
            Self {
                username
            }
        }
    }
}

enum Role {
    Administrator,
    Sponsor,
    Bot,
}

impl From<&Role> for Box<dyn BoxableExpression<roles::table, Mysql, SqlType = Nullable<Bool>>> {
    fn from(r: &Role) -> Self {
        match r {
            Role::Administrator => Box::new(roles::dsl::administrator),
            Role::Sponsor => Box::new(roles::dsl::sponsor),
            Role::Bot => Box::new(roles::dsl::bot),
        }
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let conn = MysqlConnection::establish("mysql://localhost/stquestion")?;

    diesel::replace_into(users::table)
        .values(&NewUser::new("test_account"))
        .execute(&conn)?;
    diesel::replace_into(roles::table)
        .values((
            roles::dsl::user_id.eq(1),
            <&Role as Into<
                Box<dyn BoxableExpression<roles::table, Mysql, SqlType = Nullable<Bool>>>,
            >>::into(&Role::Administrator)
            .eq(true),
        ))
        .execute(&conn)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

The above code leaves me with the following compilation error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::boxed::Box<dyn diesel::expression::BoxableExpression<stackoverflow_questions::
schema::roles::table, diesel::mysql::backend::Mysql, SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool
>>>: diesel::query_source::Column` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:36:17
   |
36 |           .values((
   |  _________________^
37 | |             roles::dsl::user_id.eq(1),
38 | |             <&Role as Into<
39 | |                 Box<dyn BoxableExpression<roles::table, Mysql, SqlType = Nullable<Bool>>>,
40 | |             >>::into(&Role::Administrator)
41 | |             .eq(true),
42 | |         ))
   | |_________^ the trait `diesel::query_source::Column` is not implemented for `std::boxed::Box<dyn diesel::expr
ession::BoxableExpression<stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::table, diesel::mysql::backend::Mysql, SqlType =
diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool>>>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::insertable::Insertable<stackoverflow_quest
ions::schema::roles::table>` for `diesel::expression::operators::Eq<std::boxed::Box<dyn diesel::expression::Boxabl
eExpression<stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::table, diesel::mysql::backend::Mysql, SqlType = diesel::sql_ty
pes::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool>>>, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql
_types::Bool>, bool>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::insertable::Insertable<stackoverflow_quest
ions::schema::roles::table>` for `(diesel::expression::operators::Eq<stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::colum
ns::user_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::mysql::types::Unsigned<diesel::sql_types::BigInt>, u64>>, di
esel::expression::operators::Eq<std::boxed::Box<dyn diesel::expression::BoxableExpression<stackoverflow_questions:
:schema::roles::table, diesel::mysql::backend::Mysql, SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Boo
l>>>, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool>, bool>>)`
```

```
>error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::boxed::Box<dyn diesel::expression::BoxableExpression<stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::table, diesel::mysql::backend::Mysql, SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool>>>: diesel::query_source::Column` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:43:10
   |
43 |         .execute(&conn)?;
   |          ^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::query_source::Column` is not implemented for `std::boxed::Box<dyn diesel::expression::BoxableExpression<stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::table, diesel::mysql::backend::Mysql, SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool>>>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::insertable::InsertValues<stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::table, diesel::mysql::backend::Mysql>` for `diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<std::boxed::Box<dyn diesel::expression::BoxableExpression<stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::table, diesel::mysql::backend::Mysql, SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool>>>, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool>, bool>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::insertable::InsertValues<stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::table, diesel::mysql::backend::Mysql>` for `(diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::columns::user_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::mysql::types::Unsigned<diesel::sql_types::BigInt>, u64>>, diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<std::boxed::Box<dyn diesel::expression::BoxableExpression<stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::table, diesel::mysql::backend::Mysql, SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool>>>, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool>, bool>>)`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_builder::QueryFragment<diesel::mysql::backend::Mysql>` for `diesel::query_builder::insert_statement::ValuesClause<(diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::columns::user_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::mysql::types::Unsigned<diesel::sql_types::BigInt>, u64>>, diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<std::boxed::Box<dyn diesel::expression::BoxableExpression<stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::table, diesel::mysql::backend::Mysql, SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool>>>, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool>, bool>>), stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::table>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_builder::QueryFragment<diesel::mysql::backend::Mysql>` for `diesel::query_builder::insert_statement::InsertStatement<stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::table, diesel::query_builder::insert_statement::ValuesClause<(diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::columns::user_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::mysql::types::Unsigned<diesel::sql_types::BigInt>, u64>>, diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<std::boxed::Box<dyn diesel::expression::BoxableExpression<stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::table, diesel::mysql::backend::Mysql, SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool>>>, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool>, bool>>), stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::table>, diesel::query_builder::insert_statement::Replace>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_dsl::load_dsl::ExecuteDsl<_, diesel::mysql::backend::Mysql>` for `diesel::query_builder::insert_statement::InsertStatement<stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::table, diesel::query_builder::insert_statement::ValuesClause<(diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::columns::user_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::mysql::types::Unsigned<diesel::sql_types::BigInt>, u64>>, diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<std::boxed::Box<dyn diesel::expression::BoxableExpression<stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::table, diesel::mysql::backend::Mysql, SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool>>>, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool>, bool>>), stackoverflow_questions::schema::roles::table>, diesel::query_builder::insert_statement::Replace>`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `stackoverflow-questions`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I've created a reproducible example for this problem [here](https://github.com/dowlandaiello/stackoverflow-questions).

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) and [Diesel-specific](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust-diesel/info) MRE tips you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Comment: Update: I've attached a link to a GitHub repo with a `Cargo.toml` file, and have added a minimal reproducible example to my original question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Using `BoxableExpression` is the wrong way here in my opinion. It's much easy to just implement `Insertable<roles::table>` manually for your enum and then directly insert the values from there.

Using this `Insertable` impl

```rust
impl Insertable<roles::table> for Role {
    type Values = <(
        diesel::dsl::Eq<roles::administrator, bool>,
        diesel::dsl::Eq<roles::sponsor, bool>,
        diesel::dsl::Eq<roles::bot, bool>,
    ) as Insertable<roles::table>>::Values;

    fn values(self) -> Self::Values {
        use crate::schema::roles;

        match self {
            Role::Administrator => (
                roles::administrator.eq(true),
                roles::sponsor.eq(false),
                roles::bot.eq(false),
            ),
            Role::Sponsor => (
                roles::administrator.eq(false),
                roles::sponsor.eq(true),
                roles::bot.eq(true),
            ),
            Role::Bot => (
                roles::administrator.eq(false),
                roles::sponsor.eq(false),
                roles::bot.eq(true),
            ),
        }
        .values()
    }
}
```

it is possible to write your insert query the following way:

```rust
    diesel::replace_into(roles::table)
        .values((roles::dsl::user_id.eq(1), Role::Administrator))
        .execute(&conn)?;
```

Comment: But would this still work if I only wanted to update one field, leaving the others intact?

Comment: In such a case the impl of `Insertable` would need to be changed a bit, but otherwise yes.

(Basically you would need to change the tuple returned by the `values` function to be `(Option<Eq<…>>, Option<Eq<…>>, Option<Eq<…>>)` and return `None` values instead of `.eq(false)`.)